# Nativescript data/observable-array don't remove items

Tags: nativescript

I following this tutorial: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

and want to remove all itens (or just a especified item by id) from a Observable-Array in NativeScript but it just cause death screen. The following code works, but not properly. Just some itens are removed, not all. What's wrong?

```
var ConstObsArray = require("data/observable-array");
var ObsArray = new ConstObsArray.ObservableArray();

function removeItens(){
    for(i = 0; i < ObsArray.length; i++)
        ObsArray.pop();
}

function onLoaded(args){
    ObsArray.push({"id":"1","title":"test notice 1"});
    ObsArray.push({"id":"2","title":"test notice 2"});
    ...
    ObsArray.push({"id":"30","title":"test notice 30"});
}
```

- I tried: ObsArray.removeAll();         // No sucess
- I tried: ObsArray.getItem(0).remove(); // No sucess
- I tried: ObsArray.get('id').remove(); // No sucess
- I tried: for(i = 0; i < ObsArray.lenght; i++) ObsArray.pop(); // Few itens removed

Comment: What's a `death screen`?

Comment: On debug, the screen shows a Log page after a critical error. I solve it using the command: `while(ObsArray.length > 0) ObsArray.pop();` but i know that isn't the best way to do it. I suspect that pop, shift and other are async function.

Comment: JavaScript array functions are synchronous unless stated otherwise in the JavaScript docs.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I never know why `for(i = 0; i < ObsArray,length; i++) ObsArray.pop()` erase few itens. I search on [link](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/5e0de0a8b84d81b52510fd979d920ae8d51956c4/tns-core-modules/data/observable-array/observable-array.ts) but i don't understand why not work. I will try another solutions.